# Does Evocations affect attacking with a polearm?

Tags: dungeon-crawl-stone-soup

According to the [Evocations page on the wiki](http://crawl.chaosforge.org/index.php?title=Evocations):

> Anything which requires the evoke command (v) uses [Evocations], as does evoking (V) wands and using special abilities (a) granted by items.

Attacking units 2 squares away with a polearm like a spear or halberd is done by using e(v)oke. What exactly is affected by your Evocations skill when doing this kind of action?

Comment: Good question.  I don't think it does anything for polearms, but I would probably have to dive into the source code to confirm that for sure.

Comment: Will update the wiki with this information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to code (for version 0.18.1) in [evoke.cc](https://github.com/crawl/crawl/blob/0.18.1/crawl-ref/source/evoke.cc#L172-L174)

```
// This chance should possibly depend on your skill with
// the weapon.
if (coinflip())
```

successfuly evoking a reach weapon (branded or polearm) depends on luck alone. And if successful, it [doesn't train evocation](https://github.com/crawl/crawl/blob/0.18.1/crawl-ref/source/evoke.cc#L2273-L2288) (`pract    = 0;`), so I gues it's an exception to that wiki page:

```
case OBJ_WEAPONS:
    ASSERT(wielded);

    if (weapon_reach(item) > REACH_NONE)
    {
        if (_reaching_weapon_attack(item))
        {
            pract    = 0;
            did_work = true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
    else
        unevokable = true;
    break;
```